# Search string within a text file

Tags: java

I'm trying to search a text file for a set of keywords.

I put them as a string and I'm having a problem with the `if` statement.

On this line:

```
if(s.contains (keywords)) {
```

I didn't have it before. It says to do the following:

> The method contains(CharSequence) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String[]))

But that just changes the String to `CharSequence`, still resulting in an error!

Here is the code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class SearchTextFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int tokencount;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\searchtxt.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s;
        int linecount = 0;

        String[] keywords = {
            "AB", "BC", "D1", "B11", "BL:", "B/1:", "B1L:", "B11:"
        };
        String line;

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.contains(keywords)) {
                System.out.println(s);
                String nextLine = br.readLine();
                System.out.println(nextLine);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You asking if the `String` contains a `array`, which unlikely to be successful, mostly because there is not such method `contains(String[])`.  Instead, you need another sub loop which loops of each of the keywoards and checks to see if they exist in the supplied `String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since String does not have the method `String.contains(String)`, you can achieve it as follows:

Change your keywords array to `ArrayList<String>`. 
Then as you read a line , get all the words in an array using `String.split()` method. Now you can loop through the word array ( created by reading the line from file) and check if the keywordList contains the word or not.
Note: `KeywordList.contains(s)` will be `true` if `s` is exactly as a keyword. It will produce `false` if `s` is a string with other words but it contains one or more elements from `keywords` array .Thus this test will not produce an effective search result. The intention of the search is to  check any input line `s` if it has at least one of the keywords from the `keywords` array. So one such solution can be as follows:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SearchTextFile
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
        int tokencount;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader("c:\\searchtxt.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s = "";
        int linecount = 0;
        ArrayList<String> keywordList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("AB", "BC", "D1", "B11", "BL:", "B/1:", "B1L:", "B11:"));

        String line;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] lineWordList = s.split(" ");
            for (String word : lineWordList)
            {
                if (keywordList.contains(word))
                {
                    System.out.println(s);
                    String nextLine = br.readLine();
                    System.out.println(nextLine);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more efficient way will be to store the list of keywords in a [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and also the list of tokens on each line in a set. This prevents the inefficiency involved in iterating over all elements of the list. With that in mind, I've modified your code slightly:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
{
    int tokencount;
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("c:\\searchtxt.txt");
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
    String s;
    int linecount=0;

    //String[]  keywords = { "AB", "BC","D1", "B11", "BL:", "B/1:","B1L:", "B11:"};
    Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("AB", "BC", "D1", "B11", "BL:", "B/1:", "B1L:", "B11:"));
    String line;
    Set<String> lineSet;

    while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
        lineSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(s.split(" ")));
        if(!Collections.disjoint(lineSet, keywords)) { //returns true if both sets have no elements in common;
            System.out.println(s);
            String nextLine = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(nextLine);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a String array (`String[]`) with `contains`, use a regex instead, i.e:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

    if (subjectString.matches("AB|BCD1|B11|BL:|B/1:|B1L:|B11:")) {
        System.out.println(s);
        String nextLine = br.readLine();
        System.out.println(nextLine);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a method as contains(String[]). The correct one is contains(String)

like @Pedro Lobito said, you could use regex. Also you could loop through your string array perhaps,

```
while ((s=br.readLine())!=null) {
    for (String str: keywords) {           
        if(s.contains (str)) {
            System.out.println(s);
            String nextLine = br.readLine();
            System.out.println(nextLine);
        }
    }
}
```